# move to given div using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my html i have got div with given class.

After clicking a button I would like to set the position to the top of that div. it may go the in smooth way .
How can I do that ?

thanks for help

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by 'set the position'? Position of what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/JU3xj/5/

Essentially, we first create a small plugin called scrollTo:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
        });
    }
});
```

Then, getting the html to scroll to that position in the DOM is very simple:

```
$('div.whatever').scrollTo(300,'linear');
```

In that code, `300` is the duration - the time it takes for the scroll to happen. The larger the number, the slower it goes. It's in milliseconds, so 1000 would equal 1 second. `linear` is the easing. For other types of easing, I'd recommend including [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)- have a look at their [easing options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html).

Comment: Thanks, works great and the post is very useful and teaches something.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [jQuery.ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), which works similarly to AlienWebguy's suggestion, but with a bunch of extra options you may find useful.